# can i inherit a parent controller's variables?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code:

```
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
$scope.people = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"];
$scope.count = $scope.people.length;
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
$scope.parentpeople = ParentCtrl.people //this is what I would like to do ideally
}
```

I am nesting one angular `controller` inside of another one. I would like to pass variables of the first `controller` to the second one. Does anyone know how to do this?

**NOTE**

I cannot do something like

```
ChildCtrl.prototype = new ParentCtrl();
```

because I will overwrite the `people` property of the `ChildCtrl`.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource any thoughts?

Comment: Use $scope.people in the child controller too -- the parent's properties are inherited.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

By default, child scopes prototypically inherit from the parent scope (see [Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)), so you already have access to the parent controller's $scope properties in the child.  To prove it:

```
function ChildCtrl($scope) {
    alert($scope.people)
}
```

Answer (score 25):

You're getting things wrong. You are mixing controller inheritance with scope inheritance, and they are different and loosly coupled in AngularJS.

What you actually want is:

```
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.people = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"];
    $scope.count = $scope.people.length;
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.parentpeople = $scope.$parent.people;
}
```

And it will work for the case:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
    </div>
</div>
```

But as Mark and ganaraj noticed above, this has no sense, as you can access your property of $scope.people from both
ParentCtrl and ChildCtrl.

If you want to inherit controllers from each other, you need to use prototype inheritance of controller functions themselves.

Comment: There's no easy way to inherit controllers in AngularJS.

Comment: Agree with your thoughts kstep.  I was just as confused as codeninja regarding this so I wrote an article on it, folks may find it useful http://www.michaeldausmann.com/2013/01/angularjs-scope-vs-controller.html

Comment: @kstep Thank you very much ! I've spent a whole day struggling to solve this issue and finally found your answer

Answer (score 9):

The $scope inheritance is based upon where you reference your controllers using ng-controller.

If you have something like

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then yes, the child controller will inherit the properties of the parent controller.

**Note :** The child controller need not be defined on the direct child in the html. It can be any child within.

Comment: I can use properties from the `Parent` in the `Child's` HTML markup, but not in the code for the `ChildController`. Do you know how to use the `Parent's` `people` property in the `Child` function?

Comment: @codeninja It would be good if you could give a more detailed requirement. What are you trying to achieve and what / where you are getting the problem!

Comment: I want to be able to use the properties of the `ParentCtrl `in the `ChildCtrl`. I dont know how to be anymore descriptive...

Answer (score 4):

Also you can get the Scope of any controller by DOM:

```
$needleScope = angular.element(aDomElement).scope()
```

Using jQuery:

```
$needleScope = $('#aDomElementId').scope()
```

Or get all Scope in the document:

```
$allScopes = $('.ng-scope').scope()
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help you!!!

Scope is a special JavaScript object that connects controller with views. Scope contains model data. In controllers, model data is accessed via $scope object.

```
<script>
      var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

      mainApp.controller("shapeController", function($scope) {
         $scope.message = "In shape controller";
         $scope.type = "Shape";
      });
</script>
```

Scope Inheritance
Scope is controller-specific. If we define nested controllers, then the child controller inherits the scope of its parent controller.

```
<script>
      var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

      mainApp.controller("shapeController", function($scope) {
         $scope.message = "In shape controller";
         $scope.type = "Shape";
      });

      mainApp.controller("circleController", function($scope) {
         $scope.message = "In circle controller";   
      });
</script>
```

Live example as give below.

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Angular JS Forms</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
       <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="shapeController">
          <p>{{message}} <br/> {{type}} </p>
          <div ng-controller="circleController">
             <p>{{message}} <br/> {{type}} </p>
          </div>
          <div ng-controller="squareController">
             <p>{{message}} <br/> {{type}} </p>
          </div>
       </div>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script>
          var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

          mainApp.controller("shapeController", function($scope) {
             $scope.message = "In shape controller";
             $scope.type = "Shape";
          });

          mainApp.controller("circleController", function($scope) {
             $scope.message = "In circle controller";   
          });

          mainApp.controller("squareController", function($scope) {
             $scope.message = "In square controller";
             $scope.type = "Square";
          });

       </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible original source: [AngularJS – Scopes](http://www.hackersit.com/angularjs-scopes/).

Comment: Possible original source: [Angular JS HTML enhanced for the web](http://slides.com/arunjames/angular-js#/11).

Comment: Possible original source: [Learn AngularJS](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_tutorial.pdf).