# $rootscope object model from service not (always) available in every controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my app definition I have:

```
var myVtModule = angular.module('vtApp', ['myAppDev','mongoAPI']);
myVtModule.run(function($rootScope, $location, Shop){
    $rootScope.shopData = {};
    Shop.getShop(function(response){
        $rootScope.shopData = response;
    });
})
```

Shop is a service retrieving data from server, it works. The problem is that in the controller I don't always have access to shopData, sometimes is empty, sometimes is working normally.

```
function SupportCtrl($rootScope, $scope) {
    console.log ($rootScope.shopData);
}
```

Why is not updating when it receives the response from the service? I can't put the Shop.getShop in the controller as I need it everywhere...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use controller inheritance and a service so that your child controllers can always have access to the shop.  Here is a demo:

http://beta.plnkr.co/edit/DtjwLMi3jHCdzThEJDNn?p=preview

Code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services']);

function MainCtrl($scope, ShopService) {
   $scope.shop = ShopService.getShop();
}
function ChildCtrl($scope) {
}
angular.module('myApp.services', []).
    factory('ShopService', function ($rootScope) {
        var shop = {
          storename: 'your store'
        };

        var service = {
              getShop: function() {
                return shop;
              }
        }

        return service;
    });
```

HTML that sets up the child controller relationship:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   The store is {{shop.storename}}
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
      The store name is: {{shop.storename}}

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You will notice that the `shop` is available to the child because the parent scope retrieved it.  I set up the service so you can make it testable/etc.   Besides the inheritance you could just as easily inject the `ShopService` into each controller and have them make the call, but if you have a lot of controllers that could become tedious.

Some more info on scope inheritance:

[can i inherit a parent controller's variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008150/can-i-inherit-a-parent-controllers-variables)
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller

Answer (score 0):

If you need the results in your controller, you should skip `myVtModule.run` and do something like this instead:

```
function SupportCtrl($scope, Shop) {
  Shop.getShop(function(response){
    console.log (response);
    //do something, put response in $scope or $scope.$rootScope etc...
  });
}
```

Comment: I can't do this as I use it in almost every controller. That's why I need to have it available from $rootScope to everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-controller scopes all prototypically inherit from rootScope (eventually), so they all have access to any objects you define on rootScope.  Since retrieving data from a server is an asynchronous operation, your controllers may execute before the server data is returned.

You can use [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) in your controllers to determine when the data is actually available.  However, if you just want your views to update when the data becomes available, you don't have to use $watch.  Angular should automatically update your views when the data becomes available.  E.g.,

```
function SupportCtrl($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.shopData = $rootScope.shopData;
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<div ng-controller="SupportCtrl">shopData = {{shopData}}</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/4x7fJ/) - I simulated a server delay using `$timeout`.  Note that in the fiddle I also use `angular.copy()` to update the reference the controller has, rather than assigning `$rootScope.shopData` to a new/different array:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $timeout){
    $rootScope.shopData = [];
    $timeout(function() {
        angular.copy([{d1: 'data1', d2: 'data2'}], $rootScope.shopData);
    }, 2000);
});
```